# How to use Haml haml_tag method with custom attributes?

Tags: html, ruby, haml

I want to reproduce the haml code below by using the `haml_tag` method.

```
= %img { alt:'Hi' , src: 'hi.jpg' }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah.. I've just realized that. There it goes:

```
- haml_tag :img, { alt:'Hi' , src: 'hi.jpg' }
```

Attention to the details of `-` instead of `=`. `haml_tag` method report directly to the haml model.

Easier than I thought. :)